# Advice on an algorithm for rendering a bitmap pixel by pixel

Tags: c, opengl, bitmap, sdl

I've been working on a bitmap loader, with the main goal to do nothing more than parse the data properly and render it in OpenGL. I'm at the point where I need to draw the pixels on an x/y (i.e., pixel by pixel) basis (at least, this is what I think I need to do as far as rendering is concerned). I've already bound the texture object and called `glTexImage2D(...)`.

Currently, what I'm having trouble with is the pixel by pixel algorithm.

As far as I understand it, bitmap (aka DIB) files store **color data** in what is known as the **pixel array**. Each row of pixels consists of `x` amount of bytes, with each pixel holding a byte count divisible either by 4 ( 32 bits per pixel ), 3 ( 24 bits per pixel ), 2 ( 16 bits per pixel ), or 1 ( 8 bits per pixel ).

**I think need to loop through the pixels while at the same time calculating the right offset within the pixel array, which is relative to its pixel x/y coordinate. Is this true, though? If not, what should I do?** I'm honestly slightly confused as to whether or not, despite doing what was directed to me in [this question I asked sometime ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187783/763053), this approach is correct.

I assume that going about it on a pixel by pixel basis is the right approach, mainly because 
rendering a quad with `glVertex*` and `glTexCoord*` produced nothing more than a grayed out rectangle (at the time I thought the OpenGL would handle this by itself, hence why attempting that in the first place).

I should also note that, while my question displays OpenGL 3.1 shaders, I moved to SDL 1.2 
so I could just use immediate mode for the time being until I got the right algorithms implemented, and then switch back to modern GL.

---

The test image I'm parsing:

[image: bitmap image]

It's data output (pastebinned due to its very long length):
http://pastebin.com/6RVhAVRq

**And The Code**:

```
void R_RenderTexture_PixByPix( texture_bmp_t* const data, const vec3 center )
{


    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, data->texbuf_id );

    glBegin( GL_POINTS );
    {
        const unsigned width  = data->img_data->width + ( unsigned int ) center[ VEC_X ];
        const unsigned height = data->img_data->height + ( unsigned int ) center[ VEC_Y ];

        const unsigned bytecount    = GetByteCount( data->img_data->bpp );

        const unsigned char* pixels = data->img_data->pixels;

        unsigned color_offset = 0;
        unsigned x_pixel;

        for ( x_pixel = center[ VEC_X ]; x_pixel < width; ++x_pixel )
        {
            unsigned y_pixel;

            for ( y_pixel = center[ VEC_Y ]; y_pixel < height; ++y_pixel )
            {

            }

            const bool do_color_update = true; //<--- replace true with a condition which checks to see if the color needs to be updated.

            if ( do_color_update )
            {
                glColor3fv( pixels + color_offset );
            }

            color_offset += bytecount;
        }
    }
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
}
```

Comment: but why do you want to do it pixel by pixel? is it not better to draw a properly sized quad (using 4 vertices). properly means that the final quad will match the size of the bitmap.

Comment: @fan, that's actually what I tried doing...which wound up confusing me, mainly because the result was a grayed out rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're completely missing the point of a OpenGL texture in your code. The texture holds the image for you and the rasterizer does all the iterations over the pixel data for you. No need to write a **slow** pixel-pusher loop yourself.

As your code stands right now that texture is completely bogus and does nothing. You could completely omit the calls to glBindTexture and it'd still work – or not, because you're not actually drawing anything, you just set the glColor state. To draw something you'd have to call glVertex.

So why not leverage the pixel-pushing performance of modern GPUs and actually use a texture? How about this:

```
void R_RenderTexture_PixByPix( texture_bmp_t* const data, const vec3 center )
{
    if( 0 == data->texbuf_id ) {
        glGenTextures(1, &(data->texbuf_id));
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, data->texbuf_id );

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        // there are a few more, but the defaults are ok
        // if you didn't change them no need for further unpack settings

        GLenum internal_format;
        GLenum format;
        GLenum type;
        switch(data->img_data->bpp) {
        case 8:
            // this could be a palette or grayscale
            internal_format = GL_LUMINANCE8;
            format = GL_LUMINANCE;
            type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
            break;

        case 15:
            internal_format = GL_RGB5;
            format = GL_BGR; // BMP files have BGR pixel order
            type = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5;
            break;

        case 16:
            internal_format = GL_RGB8;
            format = GL_BGR; // BMP files have BGR pixel order
            type = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5;
            break;

        case 24:
            internal_format = GL_RGB8;
            format = GL_BGR; // BMP files have BGR pixel order
            type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
            break;

        case 32:
            internal_format = GL_RGB8;
            format = GL_BGR; // BMP files have BGR pixel order
            type = GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8;
            break;

        }

        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format,
                      data->img_data->width, data->img_data->height, 0,
                      format, type, data->img_data->pixels );
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    } else {
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, data->texbuf_id );
    }


    static GLfloat verts[] = {
            0, 0, 
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1
    };    
    // the following is to address texture image pixel centers
    // tex coordinates 0 and 1 are not on pixel centers!
    float const s0 = 1. / (2.*tex_width);
    float const s1 = ( 2.*(tex_width-1) + 1.) / (2.*tex_width);
    float const t0 = 1. / (2.*tex_height);
    float const t1 = ( 2.*(tex_height-1) + 1.) / (2.*tex_height);
    GLfloat texcoords[] = {
            s0, t0,
            s1, t0,
            s1, t1,
            s0, t1
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texcoords);

    glColor4f(1., 1., 1., 1.);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is basically correct. The pixels are stored as an array of bytes, but the bytes are arranged into consecutive groups, with each group representing a single pixel. To address a single pixel, you'll need to do a calculation like this:

```
unsigned char* image_data = start_of_pixel_data;
unsigned char* pixel_addr = image_data + bytes_per_pixel * (y * width_in_pixels + x);
```

Be careful about the width in pixels, as sometimes there is padding at the end of the row to bring the total row width in bytes up to a multiple of 4/8/16/32/64/etc. I recommend looking at the actual bytes of the bitmap in hex first to get a sense of what is going on. It's a great learning exercise and will give you high confidence in your pixel-walking code, which is what you want. You might be able to use a debugger to do this, or else write a simple loop with `printf` over the image bytes.